# Slimport/mhl signal via usual usb cable to laptop

Tags: android, usb

is it possible to screencast from an android phone with either slimport or mhl support to a laptop with the usual usb charging cable of the phone?

Answer (score 1):

No.

First, "the usual usb charging cable" does not have the extra pins used by MHL or SlimPort.

Second, only a laptop with MHL, SlimPort, or HDMI **input** could receive a signal, even if you had the right cable. You can get some HDMI input devices that work with a laptop  for recording purposes (BlackMagic has one IIRC). I am not aware of any similar hardware for native MHL or SlimPort, though stuff could exist.

Comment: i thought it could be possible scince there are usb monitors.

Comment: @NathanMaier: From the standpoint of the laptop, a USB monitor is output, not input.